# Modal en C# en ASP.NET MVC

Tags: bootstrap, asp.net-mvc, modal

Tengo un problema, ya que tengo un proyecto en ASP.NET MVC, la idea es abrir un modal con un botón. Ya cree un `PartialView` que retorna el modal en mi ventana principal.

Al hacer click en el botón, me muestra el Modal pero se coloca encima de mi vista, y pierde de el contenido de la vista principal.

Este es el código en JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        console.log("Entre");

        $('#btnAgregar').click(function () {

            var url = $('#myModal').data('url');
            console.log(url);
            $.get(url, function (data) {

               $('#myModal').html(data);

            });


        });

    });

</script>
```

Estas son las capturas

[image: Imagen antes del click]

[image: Click al boton]

Como pueden ver el modal quita el contenido anterior, y la idea es que como todo modal se coloque encima de la ventana principal

Comment: Coloca el HTML que tienes, te darás cuenta que hay un div "myModal" está englobando a todos los demás elementos, motivo por el cual, desaparece.

Comment: identifica que el modal no sea una nueva ventana tu url no debe cambiar

Comment: Por favor, indica el código de tu Vista principal, y del PartialView que genera el Modal.